# How to reference group or shared calendar in Outlook 365 Exchange using Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, calendar

I'm trying to have multiple users be able to add an appointment to a shared calendar using Excel.

The following code works for me. I own the shared calendar and it resides in my Calendar folder in Outlook365.

```
Sub CreateAppt()

Const olFolderCalendar = 9
Const olPublicFoldersAllPublicFolders = 18
Const olAppointmentItem = 1 '1 = Appointment


Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objNameSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set items = objNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).items

'check to see if calendar exists
For i = 1 To objNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Folders.Count

If objNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Folders.Item(i).Name = "Maintenance Task Manager" Then

    'set calendar name and set new appointment
    Set objCalendar = objNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Folders("Maintenance Task Manager")
    Set objapt = objCalendar.items.Add(olAppointmentItem)

    'create appointment for PM
    With objapt
        .Subject = "PM Due for " & ActiveSheet.Range(PMcell).Offset(0, -6).Value
        .Location = ActiveSheet.Range(PMcell).Value
        .AllDayEvent = True
        .Start = ActiveSheet.Range(PMcell).Value
        .ReminderSet = True
        .ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 10080
        If Not emailaddy = "" Then
            .Recipients.Add (emailaddy)
        End If
        .BusyStatus = olFree
        .Categories = "Equipment PM's"
        .body = PersonResponsible & ", you are responsible for the PM on this piece of equipment due on " & Format(DueDate, "Long Date")
    .Save
    End With
    Exit Sub
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

The code looks for a calendar called "Maintenance Task Manager" in the Calendar folder.

[image: My nav pane]

The problem is in other users' Outlook this folder is not in the Calendar folder and therefore cannot be found. It seems to not be in any folder.

[image: Other users nav pane]

Answer (score 2):

I ended up finding a solution that works great in my situation. I had to add a new group in Outlook365 and share it with my users with read/write permissions. After they accepted, they had to add the group calendar into their favourites.

The code for anyone interested is as follows.

```
Sub Test()

Const olFolderCalendar = 9
Const olModuleCalendar = 1
Const olAppointmentItem = 1
Dim answer As Integer
Dim objNS
Dim objExpCal
Dim objNavMod
Dim objNavGroup
Dim objNavFolder
Dim objFolder
Dim colExpl

Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objNS = oApp.Session
Set colExpl = oApp.Explorers
Set objExpCal = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).GetExplorer
Set objNavMod = objExpCal.NavigationPane.Modules.GetNavigationModule(olModuleCalendar)

For Each objNavGroup In objNavMod.NavigationGroups
    For Each objNavFolder In objNavGroup.NavigationFolders
        If Not objNavFolder = "SHARED CALENDAR NAME" Then '<<must be named exactly as in the nav pane in outlook
            GoTo NxtGroup
        End If
        On Error Resume Next
        Set objFolder = objNavFolder.Folder

NxtGroup:
    Next
Next

Set objCalendar = objFolder
Set objapt = objCalendar.items.Add(olAppointmentItem)

    'create an appointment to schedule PM with outside contractor
    With objapt
        .Subject = "SUBJECT HERE"
        .Location = "LOCATION HERE
        .AllDayEvent = True 'or comment out and add an .End = line
        .Start = "SOME DATE HERE"
        .ReminderSet = True
        .ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 10080
        .BusyStatus = olFree
        .Categories = "MUST HAVE SOMETHING HERE TO BE ABLE TO DELETE THE EVENT IF NEEDED"
        .body = ""
        .Display 'or .Save
    End With

Set objNS = Nothing
Set objNavMod = Nothing
Set objNavGroup = Nothing
Set objNavFolder = Nothing
Set objFolder = Nothing
Set colExpl = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It is obtained differently than the calendar folder.

Because it is a calendar shared by others.

You can see the following link to get this folder.

[Access a Folder Opened from a Sharing Invitation](https://www.slipstick.com/developer/working-vba-nondefault-outlook-folders/)

Comment: Thanks, Evanzheng. That got me started on the right track. I ended up having to start from scratch basically.