# Loop through emails and save attachment in an Outlook 365 Group

Tags: vba, email, outlook, attachment

I am member (and one of the owners) of an Outlook 365 Group called "Reporting".
Every day "Reporting" receives emails with attachments (xls/csv).
In my Outlook application I can see the emails under Groups > Reporting.
I want to run through all unread emails of "Reporting", save the attachment on my computer and set the email as read.
I have done so for other Outlook folders.

I cannot access the Outlook 365 Group using VBA.
I searched for an answer on the net but cannot find the solution.

Code I use daily to read emails from the Folder AUTO_REPORT_NWP.

```vb
Sub Save_UnReadFiles_Auto_Report_NWP()
Dim O_App As Outlook.Application
Dim O_Space As Outlook.NameSpace 
Dim O_Folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim O_Mail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim O_Att As Outlook.Attachment
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Const AutoReport_Folder As String = "A:\2022\Werk\AUTO_REPORT_NWP"
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Dim strFilter As String
Dim TTDate As Date
Dim strFilePath As String
Dim strFileName As String
Dim MailID() As String, i As Integer, ii As Integer
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Const MailSubject_WAE_1 As String = "WD-WAE_1_email"
Const MailSubject_WAE_2 As String = "WD-WAE_2_email"
Const MailSubject_WAE_3 As String = "WD-WAE_3_email"
Const MailSubject_WAE_4 As String = "WD-WAE_4_email"
Const MailSubject_WAE_5 As String = "WD-WAE_5_email"
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Set O_App = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set O_Space = O_App.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set O_Folder = O_Space.Folders("AUTO_REPORT_NWP")
    Set O_Folder = O_Folder.Folders("Inbox")
    i = 0
    strFilter = "[UNREAD]=TRUE"
    For Each O_Mail In O_Folder.Items.Restrict(strFilter)
        TTDate = O_Mail.ReceivedTime - 1
        strFilePath = AutoReport_Folder & "\" & Format(TTDate, "mm") & ". " & Format(TTDate, "mmmm") & "\"
        strFilePath = strFilePath & Format(TTDate, "dd") & Format(TTDate, "mm") & Format(TTDate, "yy")
        strFileName = ""
        Select Case O_Mail.Subject
            Case MailSubject_WAE_1
                strFileName = "WD-WAE_1.csv"
            Case MailSubject_WAE_2
                strFileName = "WD-WAE_2.csv"
            Case MailSubject_WAE_3
                strFileName = "WD-WAE_3.csv"
            Case MailSubject_WAE_4
                strFileName = "WD-WAE_4.csv"
            Case MailSubject_WAE_5
                strFileName = "WD-WAE_5.csv"
        End Select
        If strFileName <> "" Then
            i = i + 1
            For Each O_Att In O_Mail.Attachments
                If strFileName = "keep_original_name" Then
                    On Error Resume Next
                    O_Att.SaveAsFile strFilePath & "\" & O_Att.FileName
                Else
                    On Error Resume Next
                    O_Att.SaveAsFile strFilePath & "\" & strFileName
                End If
            Next
            ReDim Preserve MailID(1 To i)
            MailID(i) = O_Mail.EntryID
        End If
    Next
    If i <> 0 Then
        For ii = 1 To UBound(MailID)
            Set O_Mail = O_Space.GetItemFromID(MailID(ii))
            O_Mail.UnRead = False
            Set O_Mail = Nothing
        Next
    End If
    Set O_Folder = Nothing
    Set O_Space = Nothing
    Set O_App = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: See if the Outlook 365 Group you describe is accessible as seen in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52655483/how-to-reference-group-or-shared-calendar-in-outlook-365-exchange-using-excel.

Answer (score 0):

Groups are not exposed as a store - neither in `MAPISession::GetMsgStoresTable` in Extended MAPI nor in `Namespace.Folders` or `Namespace.Stores` collections in Outlook Object Model. You can only access one of these folders when it is selected in Outlook through `Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder`.

Comment: The code runs via a button on the Ribbon.  First I ask the user to select the Group "Reporting".  Then I use Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder